# How to fill an array with random numbers and freeze/safe the numbers inside of the Array

Tags: java, arrays, random, fill

How can I fill an array with random numbers and than save the numbers inside the Array and don't random again?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    int[] Array = new int [10] ;
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++){
      Array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
      System.out.println(Array[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "freeze/save" numbers?

Comment: Everytime i compile the code the numbers in the array will change i dont want this

Comment: Yeah...but if you freeze the numbers, then they wouldn't really be random.  They're not really random even now, because of the seed being used.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Don't put additional information into comments, instead update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // give any random number as seed depend on which your random numbers are
        // generated
        // and as long as seed is same the random numbers generated are same
        long seed = 792839098;
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        int Array[] = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            Array[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("your same random numbers are ");
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This answer qualify your question. But if you want create same random numbers again and again the "same random numbers" sentence contradict itself. become oxymoron. they is no more place for Random.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the random number sequence to be the same each time you run the program, use `new Random(long)` to create a random number generator with a constant seed, and use that to generate the numbers.

(It is not possible to create a Java array whose elements cannot be changed.  The Java language does not support this.)